# Using Iterative Hard/Soft Thresholding in autoencoder with non linear activation

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, autoencoder, activation-function

Can someone please give an intuitive explanation of the difference between the Iterative **Hard** Thresholding VS Iterative **Soft** thresholding algorithm?

And if we can use these algorithms in an autoencoder with a **non-linear activation** function?